# How to remove html elements?

Tags: php

I'm looking at trying to get a file's contents and preview the first 50 words, excluding titles, and I've hit a snag.

```
$getPage = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    $page = "news/" . $getPage . ".php";

    $directory = 'news/';
    $scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir($directory, 1), array('..', '.'));

    if (file_exists($page)) {
    include $page;
} else {
    foreach ($scanned_directory as $value) {
        $file = file_get_contents('news/' . $value);
        $less_words = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $file), 0, 50));
        $result = preg_replace('/\<.*?\>|\s*/', '', $less_words);
    echo '<p>$result ...<br> <a href="$url">Read more</a></p>';
/* TO ADD: URL variable */
    }
}
```

The issue I am having with this is when echoing `$less_words` the text outputted is correct, however the `<h1></h1>` tags in the 2 example files I have show, and are formatted. But when echoing `$result` the text outputted on the page is `$result Read more`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php function http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php would work...

```
$file = file_get_contents('news/' . $value);
$file = strip_tags($file);
$less_words = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $file), 0, 50));
echo '<p>'.$less_words.'...<br> <a href="'.$url.'">Read more</a></p>';
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly, and for some reason didn't mess up spacing, unlike leaving the ```$result``` variable in

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
    echo '<p>$result ...<br> <a href="$url">Read more</a></p>';
/* TO ADD: URL variable */
```

to

```
echo '<p>'.$result.' ...<br> <a href="'.$url.'">Read more</a></p>';
/* TO ADD: URL variable */
```

Comment: Thanks, however for some reason doing this, but leaving everything else as is causes all the words that would be echoed to lose the spaces between them, however the strip_tags function @Barry suggested didn't do this. Don't know why though.